# Javascript string replace method doesn't work on mobile

Tags: javascript

On my website, I created a string replace method, but when I checked the page on my android phone web browser and I saw that doesn't working.
Here is the example:

```js
/*Normally it's working with page onload*/
function changeclr() {

  var body = document.getElementById('body').innerHTML;
  var all = body.replace(/&lt;/g, '<code>&lt;').replace(/&gt;/g, '&gt;</code>').replace(/&lt;/g, '<span style="color:blue;">&lt;</span>').replace(/&gt;/g, '<span style="color:blue;">&gt;</span>');

  document.getElementById('body').innerHTML = all;


}
```

```css
code {
  color: brown;
}
```

```html
<div id="body">
  <p>Here is an example &lt;li&gt;text&lt;/li&gt;</p>
  <button type="button" onclick="changeclr()">Try</button>
</div>
```

Do you know why is not working on mobile web browser?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe javascript of your browser is disabled or not supported!

Comment: I'm using Sony Xperia Z3, so it has android and google chrome web browser. I guess the problem is not web browser. (Also, other javascript functions are working)

Comment: I checked it with [link](http://www.browserstack.com) there was no error, just try another browser for testing, this time use firefox.